# How to Pattern JDBC url in XSD

Tags: xsd, restriction

I need to restrict a JDBC url is correct in XSD

```
<xs:simpleType name="JdbcUrlType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="????????"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```